# Loading content in ASP.NET MVC View delayed using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

quick question :)

I have an ASP.NET MVC view. I want the view to load and then do a post using ajax to load some secondary content. I know the Ajax.ActionLink methods etc. but I want the post to happen automatically when the page is loaded. And not based on some user action.

What is the best way to do this?

-- 
Christian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using jQuery just wire your ajax call to the $(document).ready() event.